How to resolve err: R8: Missing class android.window.BackEvent
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in /Users/admin/Desktop/mobile-app/build/flutter_inappwebview/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt.
ERROR: R8: Missing class android.window.BackEvent (referenced from: void io.flutter.view.FlutterView.startBackGesture(android.window.BackEvent) and 1 other context)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


In debug mode everything works, but when I do it in release mode The error occurs when I build the application in release mode.
I tried to add -dontwarn android.window.BackEvent in proguard-rules.pro, but it doesn't help

Could it be that you have multiple proguard-rules.pro in play? You can look at build/outputs/mapping/release/configuration.txt to see the complete configuration passed to R8.

Check your project Gradle version, mine was:
settings.gradle:
id "com.android.application" version '8.4.0' apply false
and 
gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip

After downgrading to
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
and distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip

start respecting -dontwarn android.window.BackEvent and compilation finished successfully
